# How to enable text fields on other text field click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angularjs for my form , as form load i want to disable some field, after click on a text field disable fiels should be enable. i struggle a lot on it please help me to solve that. here is my HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="signup">
<head>
 <title>Sign Up</title>
 <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/app/cmn/cmnIncludes.jsp" />
 <%-- Including login_controller.js file 
  - Date: 30Aug2016 | Author(s): Abhay Sharma --%>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/components/signup/signup_controller.js"></script>
 <%-- Including login_service.js file 
  - Date: 30Aug2016 | Author(s): Abhay Sharma --%>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/components/signup/signup_service.js"></script>
 
 <%--Including location.js --%>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/location.js"></script>
 
 
 <%--Loading the library for Google place Autocomplete --%>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyAD6LkAYd9yRpx5YlhRaRYbJClMutkxvpg&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
 
</head>

<body class="index-page signup-page">
 <!-- Navbar -->
 <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/app/cmn/header.jsp" />
 <!-- end navbar -->

 <!-- content: signup -->
    <div class="wrapper headerMargin" ng-controller="signupController">
  <div class="header header-filter" style="background-image: url('../assets/img/city.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: top center;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
      <div class="card card-signup">
       <form class="form" method="" action="" name="signupForm">
        <div class="header header-primary text-center">
         <h4>Sign Up</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">face</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person Name" ng-model="user.personName" required>
           </div>
  
           <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">business</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Firm Name" ng-model="user.firmName" required>
           </div>
  
           <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">email</i>
            </span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" required>
           </div>
           
           <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
            </span>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required/>
           </div>
  
           <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">call</i>
            </span>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" ng-model="user.number" required />
           </div>
           
           <div class="input-group" id="locationField">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">place</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="autocomplete"class="form-control" placeholder="Location" ng-model="user.place" onFocus="geolocate()" required="required" />
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="input-group">
            <!-- <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">home</i>
            </span> -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disable="" 
             placeholder="Street Address 1" id="street_number"ng-model="streetAddr1" required="required" />
           </div>
           
           <div class="input-group">
            <!-- <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">home</i>
            </span> -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disable="" 
             placeholder="Street Address 2" id="route"ng-model="streetAddr2" required="required" />
           </div> 
           
           <div class="input-group">
            <!-- <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">home</i>
            </span> -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disable="" 
             placeholder="City" id="locality" ng-model="city" required="required" />
           </div>
           
           <div class="input-group">
            <!-- <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">home</i>
            </span> -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disable=""
             placeholder="State" id="administrative_area_level_1"  ng-model="state"  required="required" />
           </div>
            
           <div class="input-group">
            <!-- <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">home</i>
            </span> -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disable=""
             placeholder="Zip Code" id="postal_code"
              ng-model="zip"  required="required" />
            
           </div>
           
           <div class="input-group">
            <!-- <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="material-icons">home</i>
            </span> -->
             <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-disable=""
              placeholder="Country" id="country" ng-model="country"  required="required" />
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <!-- If you want to add a checkbox to this form, uncomment this code
         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes" checked>
           Subscribe to newsletter
          </label>
         </div>
         -->
        </div>
        <div class="footer text-center">
         <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-simple btn-primary btn-lg"
          ng-click="signup()" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid">Signup</a>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- footer -->
 <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/app/cmn/footer.jsp" />
 <!-- end footer -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- end content -->
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to disable all fields after place and as user focus on Place , so disable field should be enable.

Comment: There is too much code please only include only essential code that's required to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a very simple example for your problem.If you disable a **input** textbox then it will not capture events. You can do one thing put **input** element within a **div** and then call your function for enable it .

I have written code for this have a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         Click to enable
         <div ng-click="enableMe()" >
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" id="inputbox" disabled >
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
         app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
             $scope.enableMe = function (){
                var element = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#inputbox' ) );
                element.removeAttr("disabled");
             }

         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<button ng-click="enabled = true">
<input ng-disabled="!enabled"/>
```

but this will only work for form elements if you want to disable link you need to use this:

```
<a ng-click="enabled && fun()">foo</a>
```

Comment: How to i can use  you code in
<a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-simple btn-primary btn-lg"
          ng-click="signup()"  ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid">Signup</a>

Comment: @AbhaySharma ng-disabled work only on form fields if you have links you can try to use `ng-click="signupForm.$invalid && signup()"`

Comment: it should be `$valid`